# Как декодировать UTF16 текст в читабельный текст c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf16le

С помощью ifstream.read считываю из файла текст в UTF16:

```
std::ifstream file("d:/example.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
char string[128] = "";
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
int data_len = (int)file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

file.read(string, data_len);
```

Текст в файле:
\u0074\u0065\u0078\u0074

И если полученный текст вывести в MessageBox, то он будет отображаться, как и в файле - со слешами, а не декодирован в читабельный.

Как можно декодировать текст?

Comment: Распарсить каждую escape последовательность в соответствующий символ.

Comment: @VTT, а можно пример?

Comment: а какая с этим сложность? тут по сути две буквы и код символа

Comment: Это всего пример. Каждый раз будет разный текст, разные символы...